# 3D View update when selecting Scene strip in VSE?

Tags: scripting, 3d-view, video-sequence-editor

Is it possible through python-scripting to let selecting a scene-strip in the sequencer automatically update a 3D view with the scene and select the camera in the scene, for further editing(see screenshot)?  If so how do I do that?

[image: 3D View updates when selecting scene strip in VSE]

The aim is something like this: [Motionbuilder Camera-Switcher video](https://youtu.be/PVb-7zyVcZo?t=36s)

Comment: I'm trying to change the scene of the 3D View area only: `bpy.data.screens['Video Editing'].areas[0].id_data.scene = bpy.data.scenes['Scene.001']` But this command changes the scene of the entire screen(all areas). Any other ideas how to do this?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do it in same screen, could open a new window.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that there was a loophole in the API, but I'm not familiar enough with it. I got the idea from Ton: https://code.blender.org/2017/10/blender-2-8-design-document/#comment-84731 So maybe the door eventually will be opened for doing this operation. Do you think it is possible, if only one scene is used, to python-script a function to select cameras in a 3D View from the sequencer? With the current API, that is?

Comment: I managed, with the help of you guys to code a script, which links the timings in the sequencer to timings of the cameras shown in the 3D Viewport(but only within the same scene). Here's the script: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?442032-Previz-Camera-Tools&p=3264762#post3264762